# is it possible to run bash commands over shell running on telnet?

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

So we have Embedded Linux board running Linux.
We can connect to that board using telnet  and that spawns shell and gives access to it.

Now I am writing a bash script where I want to run commands on that shell and get its output.

e.g. My commands are something like below command over telnet and see if that was successful or not.

```
test -c /dev/null
```

When I run it like below I always get `1` as exit status

```
{ test -c /dev/null; sleep 1;} | telnet <board ip addr>
```

If possible I don't want to use expect,

Any suggestion/pointers ?

Comment: Can you install ssh server on that Linux board ?

Comment: Nope can't install ssh :(

Answer (score 1):

With SSH could trivially and robustly have done:

```
ssh yourhost 'test -c /dev/null'
```

With a simple shell on a TCP port, you could somewhat robustly but annoyingly have used:

```
echo 'test -c /dev/null; echo $?' | nc -q 1 yourhost 1234
```

`telnet` is instead notoriously timing sensitive and tricky to script, so since you don't want to do it robustly with `expect`, you can try to kludge it:

```
{ sleep 1; echo 'test -c /dev/null; echo $?'; sleep 1; } | telnet somehost
```